# Mesh `Cylinder[{{0,0,0},{0,0,1}},1]` with inner boundary `x=y=0`

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

In a meshed cylinder  `Cylinder[{{0,0,0},{0,0,1}},1]`  I need to specify `DirichletConditions` along `x=y=0`.

How to define such a 3D mesh with additional inner boundary?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure whether this works in 3D, but this should answer your question if it does: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207285/how-to-mesh-a-region-with-inclusions-touching-the-boundary

Comment: @LukasLang Thank you, I have to try it out. Unfortunately I'm not able to mesh the line in 3D: `ToElementMesh[Line[...]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ToBoundaryMesh[..., "IncludePoints" -> myAdditionnalPoints] seems to be the solution :

```
myAdditionnalPoints = Table[{0, 0, h}, {h, 0, 1, 1/50}];

boundaryMesh = 
 ToBoundaryMesh[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1], 
  "IncludePoints" -> myAdditionnalPoints]

boundaryMesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements"]]
```

[image]

Checking that the points are still there after full-meshing :

```
fullMesh = ToElementMesh[boundaryMesh]
fullMesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements"]]
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is  simple but it took me hours to find it !

Comment: Looks good, thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately ther are no linelements: `Cases[boundaryMesh["BoundaryElements"], Line[p_] :> p, -1]   (*{}*)`

Comment: I don't understand, Dirichlet conditions do not need some "LineElements" : Only PointElements are necessary

Comment: Thanks , I expected a line for the inner bc and a set of triangles outside. I will test the DirichletCondition. By the way`Cases[boundaryMesh["BoundaryElements"], Point[p_] :> p, -1]` gives `{}` too

Comment: You 're right, I could solve my Dirichlet-problem "pointwise"